# Extracting JSON data using Newtonsoft in xamarin.android

Tags: json, xamarin.android

Hello I am getting JSON data from server and i want to extract that JSON in Xamarin. How can i parse that JSON using NewTonSoft

below is the JSON responce i receive

```
[
  {
    "Id": 5,
    "AlbumKey": "2REC2ZDSFK",
    "ZipFillPath": "aaaa@gmail.com\\2REC2ZDSFK",
    "NoOfPages": 3,
    "EmailID": "aaaa@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be your Model

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AlbumKey { get; set; }
    public string ZipFillPath { get; set; }
    public int NoOfPages { get; set; }
    public string EmailID { get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
RootObject myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

If your json is a List of objects, something like

```
List<RootObject> myListObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

Comment: RootObject myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
 is not working

Comment: which is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class yourClass

{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string AlbumKey { get; set; }
  public string ZipFillPath { get; set; }
  public int NoOfPages { get; set; }
  public string EmailID { get; set; }
}
```

Considering this  as your model class you can

```
var responseText= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<yourClass>(jsonResponse);
```

Then depending on if its a list or a not you can get the data from it

In case you are unable to find the class what you can do is check if the namespace of your current class and that class is the same.